# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project marytts-lang-en: There are test failures

Tags: java, marytts

I'm trying to build the maryTTS open Source text-to-speech engine , But i'm getting test-failures please help me out on this error

```
Command i have used to build maryTTS project (Branch 5.x) is 

**avinash@lb:~/lb-work/text-to-speach-engine/mary5.x/marytts$ mvn install**

error is pasted below 


Tests run: 23, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 22

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] MaryTTS ........................................... SUCCESS [2.755s]
[INFO] marytts-common .................................... SUCCESS [8.488s]
[INFO] marytts-signalproc ................................ SUCCESS [8.237s]
[INFO] marytts-runtime ................................... SUCCESS [18.343s]
[INFO] marytts-lang-de ................................... SUCCESS [2.912s]
[INFO] marytts-lang-en ................................... FAILURE [3.120s]
[INFO] marytts-lang-te ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-lang-tr ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-lang-ru ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-lang-it ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-lang-fr ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-lang-sv ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-lang-lb ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-languages ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] voice-cmu-slt-hsmm ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-client .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-builder ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-redstart .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-transcription ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-assembly-builder .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-assembly-runtime .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] marytts-assembly .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 44.511s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 14 12:00:06 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/552M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
>   (default-test) on project marytts-lang-en: There are test failures.
>
> [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] Please refer to /home/avinash/lb-work/text-to-speach-engine/mary5.x/marytts/marytts-languages/marytts-lang-en/target/surefire-reports
>   for the individual test results.
>           [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>           [ERROR] 
>           [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>           [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>           [ERROR] 
>           [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>           [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
>           [ERROR] 
>           [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
>           [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :marytts-lang-en

Answer (score 0):

can you try doing "clean install" in 'Goals' ? Click on "Skip Tests" checkbox while running it.

Comment: I got the solution actually the problem with the branch i'm trying to run .
Adding new language in MaryTTS is supports only for MaryTTS 5.x branch it doesn't support in master branch

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution actually the problem with the branch i'm trying to run . Adding new language in MaryTTS is supports only for MaryTTS 5.x branch it doesn't support in master branch